# Grouping treeview powerbuilder

Tags: treeview, powerbuilder, datawindow

Is it possible to group 2 rows into one ?
e.g.

```
Revenue
-Unit

Revenue
-Parts
```

to

```
Revenue
-Unit
-Parts
```

The `Revenue` is a compute field with a expression `if(account_main_short_title='UNIT' or account_main_short_title='PARTS','Revenue','')`
I've done already playing with datasource and ask Mr. Google but still i cant fix my problem still trying to fix this for almost 5hrs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are looking to put labels on a report and not actual values (sums)?  The computed field you demonstrate will result in the word 'Revenue' or an empty string being shown.

Comment: yes, and i want to divide them depending on the header like (Revenue,Expenses,etc..) but thank you for the reply, i played with `sort` yesterday and i did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is closed, i already answer my own question by playing the `sort` in datawindow, i just added the `category` which is my `compute field`.
Thanks.